# File upload with pure nodejs

Tags: node.js, http

i am trying to upload a file with pure nodejs

```
      var req = require('https').request(myoptions, function afterRequestSend(req,res){
        // THIS BLOCK NEVER CALLED. WHY ?
      });
      var boundayKey = 'abc';
      req.write(
        '--' + boundaryKey + '\r\n'
        + 'Content-Type: '+ ('application/octet-stream') +'\r\n'
        + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="'+ ('file1') +'"; filename="'+ ('filename') +'"\r\n'
      );
      someReadableStream.pipe(req, { end : false });
      someReadableStream.once('end',req.end.bind(req,'\r\n--' + boundaryKey + '--'));
      someReadableStream.once('error',reject);
```

And its never ending process after then

```
HTTP 17278: sockets service.com:443::::::::: 2
HTTP 17278: write ret = false
HTTP 17278: write ret = false
HTTP 17278: write ret = false
HTTP 17278: write ret = false
HTTP 17278: CLIENT socket onClose
HTTP 17278: removeSocket service.com:443::::::::: writable: false
HTTP 17278: HTTP socket close
HTTP 17278: write ret = true
HTTP 17278: outgoing message end.
```

The after request callback is never called.
Any help?

PS : I am not willing to use any lib. Just pure nodejs.

Comment: There is too much code missing here. You will have to provide more context

Comment: Does that helps? I removed all clutter.. Now my focus is to pipe a readable stream to request.. and i am just wondering why request callback never ends

Comment: Take a look at the upload libraries, like multer, for inspiration

Comment: @JimFactor multer depends on busboy and dicer. all large projects. i don't think it's that simple. then, mscdex is not famous for his easy to understand code.

Comment: It is just simple file upload.. why do i need a third party lib..? Isn't that possible with pure node..?

Comment: Node has a smaller core library as compared to something like python or php